# CloudFront with S3 origin is not compressed

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I followed AWS guideline step by step, I added Content-Length header to allowed headers on S3 but Im still not getting uncompressed response from Cloudfront

Response directly from S3:

[image]

Response from CloudFront:

[image]

CloudFront is configured to compress objects

[image]

Only original file from google is compressed:

[image]

CORS S3 setting:

```
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "Authorization",
            "Content-Length"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "GET"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "*"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": [],
        "MaxAgeSeconds": 3000
    }
]
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After few days of desperately digging I found this blogpost that answered all my questions especially one.

What is x-content-encoding-over-network header

It was actually ESET antivirus that decompress the response scanned it and than pass it to the browser. So CloudFront was actually working all the time.

https://medium.com/@mishani0x0ef/iis-compression-the-mental-model-a0b4fad78c74